# Выбивает ошибка при попытке отправить форму

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Выбивает ошибка при попытке отправить форму
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\OrderRequest] does not exist.

Файл `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
}
```

Файл `OrderController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Requests;


class OrderController extends Controller {

    public function submit(OrderRequest $req) {
        // $validation = $req->validate([
        //     'name' => 'required',
        //     'year_old' => 'required'
        // ]);
    }
}
```

Файл `OrderRequest.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class OrderRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // 'name' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

[image: Дерево проекта]

Comment: Вам не кажется необходимым указать `use ...\OrderRequest` в файле `OrderController.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыт импорт файла реквеста, `use App\Http\Requests\OrderRequest;`